# Tiled Map and Picture Marker Symbol not rendered using Print Task with ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have located a hospital and provided a new symbol to it. Also added a STREETS basemap to it.

I can see both of them on the map on screen. But when I try to generate a report (using Print Task), every detail is present in the report, except for the symbol and the basemap.

This is how I added the basemap:

```
    var url = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services
              /World_Street_Map/MapServer";
    var tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(url,{"id":"Streets"});
    map.addLayer(tiledLayer);
```

This is how I added the Picture Marker Symbol:

```
    myLayer.add(new Graphic
    (
        locateFeature.geometry, featureicon2, locateFeature.geometry.attributes
    ));
```

Both of them are rendered on the map but not in the report (after the Print Task is executed).

Is there any way to get them rendered? Please help!